# List of Folder/Filenames (string) - take only first File in Folder - possible via Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I receive a list of Files, and the Folders that they reside in

I can only process 1 File per folder at any stage - and need to return the
first file per folder (after these first files are processed, they will be removed from the list)

Thus if I have input:

```
/Foldername1/OrderNo1.csv
/Foldername2/OrderNo2.csv
/Foldername1/OrderNo3.csv
/Foldername3/OrderNo4.csv
/Foldername2/OrderNo5.csv
```

It should return

```
/FolderName1/OrderNo1.csv
/FolderName2/OrderNo2.csv
/FolderName3/OrderNo4.csv



public void Main()
{
 RunThis();
}
public class Order
{
    public string OrderNo;
    public int CustomerID;
}
private void RunThis()
{
    List<Order> o = new List<Order>()
    {
        new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername1/OrderNo1.csv",CustomerID = 1},
        new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername2/OrderNo2.csv",CustomerID = 7},
        new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername1/OrderNo3.csv",CustomerID = 8},
        new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername3/OrderNo4.csv",CustomerID = 12},
        new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername2/OrderNo5.csv",CustomerID = 8},
    };


   Console.WriteLine(o);                        

}
```

Is this possible via Linq or is it only possible via
creating 2 arrays
1. to keep the list of processed folders
2. to keep the list of first files in folder

```
Loop each filename
  if processed folder does not contain files Directory Name
     add foldername to processedfolders
     add file to list of first files
  end if 
next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by [directory name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) and take first file from each group:

```
List<Order> list = new List<Order>()
{
    new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername1/OrderNo1.csv",CustomerID = 1},
    new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername2/OrderNo2.csv",CustomerID = 7},
    new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername1/OrderNo3.csv",CustomerID = 8},
    new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername3/OrderNo4.csv",CustomerID = 12},
    new Order { OrderNo = "/Foldername2/OrderNo5.csv",CustomerID = 8},
};

var files = list.GroupBy(o=>Path.GetDirectoryName(o.OrderNo)).Select(o=>o.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ the way to handle this is to group the records, sort the groups if required, then use the `First` method to return a single item from each group.

In your specific case the grouping term will be the folder name, which you can extract with the `Path.GetDirectoryName` method.  Sorting can be done prior to the grouping operation and should retain the requested ordering:

```
var query = 
    from ord in list
    orderby ord.OrderNo
    group ord.OrderNo by Path.GetDirectoryName(ord.OrderNo) into grp
    select grp.First();
```

The resulting records from this:

```
/Foldername1/OrderNo1.csv 
/Foldername2/OrderNo2.csv 
/Foldername3/OrderNo4.csv
```